# Is it possible to fully automate the kvm install of ubuntu-core (ie without any terminal prompts)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core, preseed

When I follow the ubuntu-core install instructions for kvm,
and run the step:

```
kvm -smp 2 -m 1500 \
  -netdev user,id=mynet0,hostfwd=tcp::8022-:22,hostfwd=tcp::8090-:80 \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet0 \
  -vga qxl -drive file=ubuntu-core-18-amd64.img,format=raw
```

There are a few prompts in the terminal window (ubuntuone login, password, etc...) that I would like to pre-answer without having to type anything in the terminal.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

after following [guides](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/image-building) or [tutorials](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-own-core-image?_ga=2.125529738.1289851785.1571375380-2114895731.1569476674#0) to build custom images it seems to be a common question [how to preconfigure](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/preconfigure-ubuntu-core-image-that-does-not-require-store-account-login-on-first-boot/7994) it.

One [answer](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-preconfigure-custom-image/4154) I found in article was using e.g. an USB thumb drive plugged into the device that initializes core (think in a factory or other phys deployment). In your example you can very much do the same with another virtual drive provided to the guest providing the same data.

Since I'm usually a big fan of customization via cloud-init there is a way to do it that way as well (less device centric, more cloud thinking) which is [described](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-preconfigure-custom-image/4154/15) in the same thread. It even comes with a great [example github project](https://github.com/americademy/ubuntu-core-image-example) how to use it.

I personally think using cloud-init has slightly higher entry cost to set things up but will allow you a much more reliable and flexible image customization as [cloud-init can do so much more](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).